# SQL join with same if exists, if not, any

Tags: sql-server

I need to update a column with the prices of products. The product can be identical as the order or can be similar to the order.
When te product is identical, it's easy.
But when the product is similar, not all the characteristics are equal to the order table, and I don't know how to do the match.
So far, I've writed a query like this:

```
Update #SelledProducts
Set S.Price=O.Price
FROM 
#SelledProducts S, #OrdersWithPrice O
WHERE S.MandatoryCharacteristic1=O.MandatoryCharacteristic1
AND   S.MandatoryCharacteristic2=O.MandatoryCharacteristic2
AND   S.MandatoryCharacteristic3=O.MandatoryCharacteristic3
--Te following is wrong:
...
AND   S.OptionalCharacteristic1=O.OptionalCharacteristic1
AND   S.OptionalCharacteristic2=O.OptionalCharacteristic2
```

But of course it's not working when the OptionalCharacteristics are not equal. With optional characteristic, I mean:
The order can have a red box, but if there are no red boxes, there can be any color boxes for the same order.

How can I achive this? I'm using SQL Server 2008.
Thanks

Comment: What would be wrong with just ORing together the conditions in the `ON` clause, and can you show us some sample data?

Comment: Evolve. No one should be using old-style joins via the where clause.

Comment: Use proper `JOIN`.  It's been around for over 20 years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `OR` Condition instead of `AND` in your query for optional Characteristics.
Please find below example for it.

```
Update #SelledProducts
Set S.Price=O.Price
FROM 
#SelledProducts S, #OrdersWithPrice O
WHERE S.MandatoryCharacteristic1=O.MandatoryCharacteristic1
AND   S.MandatoryCharacteristic2=O.MandatoryCharacteristic2
AND   S.MandatoryCharacteristic3=O.MandatoryCharacteristic3
--Te following is wrong:
...
AND ( S.OptionalCharacteristic1=O.OptionalCharacteristic1
OR   S.OptionalCharacteristic2=O.OptionalCharacteristic2)
```